# PHP access denied for MySQL SHA256 Accounts

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ssl

I've compiled OpenSSL 1.0.2h into /usr/local/openssl on a MySQL 5.7.13 Server, using the following code:

```
tar xvzf openssl-1.0.2h.tar.gz -C /usr/local
cd /usr/local/openssl-1.0.2h
./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl shared
make depend
make
make install
```

After, I configured MySQL with:

```
cmake . -DMYSQL_DATADIR=/usr/local/mysql/dat -DWITH-SSL=/usr/local/openssl
```

When MySQL starts for the first time, it creates eight key/cert (.pem) files within that **/dat** directory:

1. ca.pem
2. ca-key.pem
3. client-cert.pem
4. client-key.pem
5. private_key.pem
6. public_key.pem
7. server-cert.pem
8. server-key.pem

From within MySQL Workbench, I can see that SSL is on in the Available Server Features:

- SSL Availability **On** (Green Dot)

And that the SHA256/SSL files are identified in the Authentication section:

- SHA256 password private key: **private_key.pem**
- SHA256 password public key: **public_key.pem**
- SSL CA: **ca.pem**
- SSL CA path: **n/a**
- SSL Cert: **server-cert.pem**
- SSL CRL: **n/a**
- SSL CRL path: **n/a**
- SSL Key: **server-key.pem**

From the **Users and Privileges** section in Workbench I have created two test users:

> 'user_standard'@'%' picking **Standard** for Authentication Type
>
> 'user_sha256'@'%' picking **SHA256 Password** for Authentication Type

In my **my.cnf** file I specify the following:

```
[client]
ssl-ca = /usr/local/mysql/dat/ca.pem
ssl-cert = /usr/local/mysql/dat/client-cert.pem
ssl-key = /usr/local/mysql/dat/client-key.pem

[mysqld]
ssl-ca = /usr/local/mysql/dat/ca.pem
ssl-cert = /usr/local/mysql/dat/server-cert.pem
ssl-key = /usr/local/mysql/dat/server-key.pem
ssl-cipher = DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
```

The "status" of the MySQL Server is as follows:

```
mysql> status
--------------
./bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.13, for Linux (x86_64) using   EditLine wrapper

Connection id:           4
Current database:        mysql
SSL:                     Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Current page:            stdout
Using outfile:           ''
Using delimiter:         ;
Server version:          5.7.13-debug-log Source distribution
Protocol version:        10
Connection:              Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:     utf8
Db     characterset:     utf8
Client characterset:     utf8
Conn.  characterset:     utf8
UNIX socket:             /tmp/mysqld.sock
```

I have a separate client server running **Apache 2.4.10** (configured with *--with-ssl=/usr/local/openssl*), **PHP 7.0.7** (configured with *--with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl*), and the same **OpenSSL 1.0.2h** (configured with *--prefix=/usr/local/openssl shared*).  My phpinfo.php file shows **OpenSSL support** is *enabled* and that its Library/Header Version is indeed **1.0.2h**.

I then copied the **ca.pem**, **server-cert.pem**, and **server-key.pem** files from the MySQL Server to the Apache/PHP Server and made a directory to put them in: **/usr/local/openssl/ssl/mysql/**.

Here is my PHP code that is a "Success!" using the credentials for [user_standard] but I get,

> **Warning:** mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'user_sha256' (using password: YES)

simply switching the **$user** and **$pass** variables to log in as [user_sha256]. Everything else remains the same.

```
$conn = mysqli_init();
$conn->options (MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);
$conn->ssl_set ('/usr/local/openssl/ssl/mysql/server-key.pem', '/usr/local/openssl/ssl/mysql/server-cert.pem', '/usr/local/openssl/ssl/mysql/ca.pem', NULL, 'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA');

$serv = 'MySQL_Server_5.7.13_Auto_Generated_Server_Certificate';
$user = 'user_standard';  // Switching to 'user_sha256' = Permission denied
$pass = 'user_standard';  // Switching to 'user_sha256' = Permission denied
$data = 'test';

$conn->real_connect ($serv, $user, $pass, $data, 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);

if (!$conn) {
    die ('Connect error (' . mysqli_connect_errno(). '): ' . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n");
} else {
    echo "Success!";
}

$conn->close();
```

I don't understand the difference and/or what possibly needs to be configured differently to allow PHP to connect to the SHA256 account.

And by the way, both the MySQL Server and the Apache/PHP Server are: **CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)**.